# Merge three lines into one multi color

Tags: reactjs

Currently I have three lines with different colors. I need to make it one colorful line that starts with first color and ends with the last one. Here is the picture [image]

And here is the styles

```
let container = {
        display: display,
        width: left,
        height: '3px',
        backgroundColor: item.lineColor,
        // position: 'absolute',
```

With `position: absolute` it makes one line but with the last color(red). How can I make it a multicolor proper line?

Answer (score 1):

Playing With `z-index` can turn out tricky real fast **because** of the stacking context.

A more natural way of dealing with this would be to simply reverse the order of the lines in the markup:

The red (last) line appears on top of the others because that's how the browser naturaly stacks content.

Instead of adding the lines in the markup in the order `yellow, blue, red`, just reverse it to `red, blue, yellow`.

This way the blue line will cover the red and the yellow will cover the blue, appearing as a three section line.

```css
.container {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  position: relative;
}

.line3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  width: 66%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: red;
}

.line2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.line1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  width: 33%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line3"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `position: absolute`, you can form a `stacking context` to display one single colorful line by assigning each line a `z-index` value. Just give higher `z-index` value to the line that you want it to be displayed at the top. Using `position: absolute` together with `z-index` can solve your issue.

For reference regarding `stacking context` you can visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context#The_example)